# When I am trying to add an item to my to do list, I m getting an IntegrityError

Tags: python, django

I am building an todo app with Register, Login, Logout functionalities, I created a TaskForm to let user create their tasks, but when is click add it gives an

IntegrityError at / NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks_task.user_id

I tried many different approaches but it gives the same error 
it works when i add user in fields in TaskForm but it creates a Dropdown list of All users

tasks/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Task(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tasks")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}:{self.user}"
```

tasks/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
```

tasks/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import TaskForm
from .models import Task
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    form = TaskForm()
    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "tasks/home.html", context )
```

tasks/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name= 'home' )
]
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'users/layout.html' %}
{%  load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}

<div class="container pt-5 ">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p style="text: 'center'">User: {{ user.get_username }}</p>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" >Create Task</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login Here</a>
    {% endif %}
    <div class = "container">
        <ul>
            {% for task in tasks %}
            {% if task in user.tasks.all %}
                <li>{{ task.name }}</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
                <li>No Tasks for Today</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Task

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        task = super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
        'name',
        'user'
        ]


views.py

# You can save the user with form object then

@login_required
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            form_obj.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    form = TaskForm()
    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "tasks/home.html", context )
```

Comment: it creates a drop down list of users but i want to create task for logged in user automatically

Comment: you can save the user with form object.

Comment: i have inserted save function in there

Comment: yes, you have used save function. But have you used 'form_obj.user = request.user' before saving the form object. I made some changes in my answer for that.

Comment: bro now it is giving KeyError at /
'user' i think its because of form_obj.user = request.user

Comment: can you look at my whole code on github HardikDhuri
/
My-Todo-App-Login-

Comment: Ohk, it must have user field in the form TaskForm.

Comment: I spent almost 2 days on this bug . I will be very grateful to you

Comment: You have to add user field in your form 'TaskForm'. I have updated my answer.